# Delete a Firebase user as an Admin within the Client

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I want to give the possibility to the admins to delete users from within the client. By deleting I mean to remove the users from the Authentication list.

Until now, I have only found unsatisfactory ways to delete users. e.g.

```
 final currentUser = await Firebase.currentUser();
 currentUser.delete();
```

But this only holds for the current user and not for another.

I also found that I could do this with cloud functions, which I am not familiar with.

Is there a way to do this within the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no other way than admin-SDK. You can use admin-SDK or cloud functions to do this.

```
admin.auth().deleteUser(uid)
  .then(function() {
    console.log('Successfully deleted user');
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error deleting user:', error);
  });
```

Admin SDK is available in nodejs, java, GO, C# and python.

Detailed guide on admin sdk [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users)